# java.lang.NumberFormatException when trying to connect to HBase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am setting HBase configuration `new HBaseGraphConfiguration().set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE)` where

`ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE = "172.31.17.251:2181,172.31.17.252:2181,172.31.17.253:2181";`

However it throws an `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, the part of the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2181]"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.<init>(ConnectStringParser.java:72)
```

The console output before the error line is

```
2018-05-30 14:40:52 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253:2181] sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection-0x25a65b770x0, quorum=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253:2181], baseZNode=/hbase
2018-05-30 14:40:52 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253:2181] sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection-0x25a65b770x0, quorum=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253:2181], baseZNode=/hbase
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps the probem is obvius but just in case the problem is that port number has the closing bracket, so as it is it can't be converted into a number. If it is part of a configuration file, try leaving a space before the bracket.

Comment: @Juan The variable does not have any bracket and in console log output it has `connectString=[*,*,*]`, which means these two brackets are added by the parser? And there is no error for the first bracket `[` but an error for the second one `]`

Comment: @Juan One more thing I need to add is, if I set `ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE = "172.31.17.251,172.31.17.252,172.31.17.253";` the variable will become `connectString=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253]:2181`

Comment: Please attach your code. And base `For input string: "2181]"`, I guess you spilt your string array with `:`. You need to convert array to list then spilt one by one.

Comment: @Bejond My code is just as the line above, `ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE = "172.31.17.251:2181,172.31.17.252:2181,172.31.17.253:2181";` this is the zookeeper quorum String, and I guess why it is converted to the list is that this `ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE` String is parsed by the official `org.apache.hbase` package

Comment: The Zookeeper port should default to 2181. It's not a brilliant solution, but have you tried omitting the ports?

Comment: @BenWatson Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it. As I depicted in the answer below. The error goes from the second bracket to the first bracket. However, I would try `HBaseConfiguration` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer of @VS_FF, I have found the issue and also now posting the whole answer

The short solution of this problem is just set `conf.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);`

First it is suggested to set the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum = "ip1,ip2,ip3"` (host ip) and `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort = 2181` (port) separately.

The string of ip addresses are inputted to HBase configuration . Then, it has two sorts of parsing method, controlled by

```
conf = new PropertiesConfiguration();
conf.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
```

if this `setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true)` is applied, then configuration will input the origin string to zookeeper, saying `"ip1,ip2,ip3"`, otherwise `setDelimiterParsingDisabled(false)` (this is the default setting), in this condition, it will input an array to zookeeper, saying `[ip1,ip2,ip3]`.

However, zookeeper need to get a `String` variable, so if `setDelimiterParsingDisabled(false)`, it will first convert the array to `String`, adding the brackets `[]`.

Finally, zookeeper parse the `String` variable by using split of notation `,`, that is why it finally gets `ip1 = "[ip1", ip2 = "ip2", ip3 = "ip3]"` and throws an `NumberFormatException`

Comment: in which file are these suggested changes to be made?

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions for you to try to debug around this:

First, there is a separate property that you can supply for the client port specifically, instead of using the `IP:port` notation: `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` So try supplying those two parameters separately -- one a comma delimited list of addresses and the second parameter just this one number (I pass it as a string though, so `"2181"`)

Second, IMPORTANT: be careful with supplying IP addresses here in general, as HBase seems very picky in terms of IP addresses and host names. Much better to use host names and to put those IP addresses in `/etc/hosts` file on your client along with the desired host names

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I took a look at the HBase configuration document and the `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` is `2181` by default. And as my comment above, if I just set `ZOOKEPER_QORUM_NODE = "172.31.17.251,172.31.17.252,172.31.17.253";` it would become `connectString=[172.31.17.251:2181, 172.31.17.252:2181, 172.31.17.253]:2181` and error is `java.net.UnknownHostException: [172.31.17.251: invalid IPv6 address`

Comment: So as you mentioned, I had set these 2 parameters separately, I think this is what you mean?

Comment: Hmm yes, I meant supply host names without the port number, and just set the port number separately via the hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort property (or in fact try not setting it at all, as you are using default).

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using HBaseGraphConfiguration() to set these properties rather than the usual HBaseConfiguration ?

Comment: I will check if I can use `HBaseConfiguration`, before that I found another issue, see `java.net.UnknownHostException: [172.31.17.251: invalid IPv6 address`, why this bracket is included in the ip address and...finally it did cause an error?

Comment: Well clearly this looks like a bad IP address -- it has an opening brace, an unnecessary ':', and no closing brace. This clearly seems like a parsing issue, so the question is where it's happening. Clearly not in your code, so I was wondering if there is something inside that HBaseGraphConfiguration module, which I have never used. Tehre shouldn't be any issues with using the standard HBaseConfiguration -- at least try it to isolate the problem. Also, can't stress enough -- dont use IP addresses, use host names with HBase!

Comment: I have traced back to the source code and I think I found the issue and post it as an answer. Would you like to check if it is correct? Thanks for giving these useful suggestions above!